# I've a problem trying to create users with roles

Tags: 7, testing

I'm using simpletest_clone to do my tests.
what i want now is just to create an user for every existing role i've created
(I dont need just the list of permissions, i need the user to have the exact role i want)

```
public function testProbando(){
 foreach(user_roles() as $clave => $rol){
   $this->privilegedUser=$this->drupalCreateUser(array());
   $this->privilegedUser->roles = array($clave => $rol);
   user_save($this->privilegedUser);
   $this->drupalLogin($this->privilegedUser);
   $this->drupalLogout();
 }
}
```

but in the verbose it simply doesn't log in and i can't get any clue what to do

Comment: How many roles are defined in your test before you try to create users? Tests set up a new skeleton of a site and it won't have the roles that your current site has unless they're defined in the test.

Comment: mmmmmm from 20 to 30, im not sure, anyway... i'm using simpletest_clone so , at least i get all the roles i had i my site using user_roles()

Comment: I'm not sure what "from 20 to 30" means for which roles are created. Try `$this->debug(user_roles())` to see what roles exist in your test.

Comment: Just a note, but you might want to consider using `user_roles(TRUE)` to exclude the anonymous user.